# java.net.Socket > outputStream > BufferedOutputStream flush() confirmation

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

is there a way of knowing when or whether the flush() method of a BufferedOutputStream thread has finished successfully? In my case I'm using it for sending a simple string through a java.net.Socket. In the following code, the flush() method is run in parallel with the BufferedReader.read() method and the socket output is immediately blocked by the input read resulting in something that resembles a deadlock. What I would like to do is wait for the output to end, and then start reading the input.

```
Socket sk = new Socket("192.168.0.112", 3000);
BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
bo.write(message.getBytes());
bo.flush();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
String line = br.readLine();
if (line.equals("ack")) {
    System.out.println("ack");
}


sk.close();
```

*Update*

ServerSocket:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
        System.out.println("server socket open");
        while (true) {
            Socket sk = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("new connection");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
            String line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("received line: " + line);
            BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
            bo.write("ack".getBytes()); bo.flush();
            sk.close();
        }
```

*Update*:

@Global Variable - the reason that read was blocking the socket is that it was waiting for the \n, indeed. Using

```
bo.write("ack\n".getBytes());
```

instead of

```
bo.write("ack".getBytes());
```

made it work.

Regarding the initial question, is there a way of knowing if flush() method has finished successfully, @Stephen C provided the answer:

> there is no way to know that based on the Socket or OutputStream APIs.
>   The normal way to get that sort of assurance is to have the remote
>   application send an "reply" in response, and read it in the local
>   side.

This "reply" is implemented in the code sample and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is reading `reader.readLine()` . Are your writing \n when writing? You may want to append \n to the string your are writing.

Comment: OK, that's an idea, but what would the alternative to reader.readLine() be? I've used it before and it worked without \n.

Comment: You can use inputstream.read(). But then you will have to negotiate your own message boundaries as special bytes or characters (to be able to tell one message from another)

Comment: The thing is that everything works fine (the server receives the message, with or without the line ending) if the socket inputStream is not listening for a message. The socket deadlock occurs because writing and reading are parallel threads, as triggered by the code above. I think output has a lower priority than input; in this case there's no way an ACK is received if the message hasn't been sent.

Comment: I mean the read() and flush() methods. They trigger IO threads that share a resource - the Client socket.

Comment: "The ObjectInputStream constructor blocks until it completes reading the serialization stream header. Code which waits for an ObjectInputStream to be constructed before creating the corresponding ObjectOutputStream for that stream will deadlock, since the ObjectInputStream constructor will block until a header is written to the stream, and the header will not be written to the stream until the ObjectOutputStream constructor executes. This problem can be resolved by creating the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream, [...]."

Comment: [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html)

Comment: Any idea where I could find a good inputStream.read() example? Everything I've found so far uses bufferedReader.readLine() and my implementation of inputStream.read() or bufferedReader.read() blocks the thread.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of knowing when or whether the `flush()` method of a `BufferedOutputStream` thread has finished successfully?

It depends on what you mean by "finished successfully".

The `flush()` method ensures that all unsent data in the pipeline has been pushed as far as the operating system network stack.  When that is done, then you could say that `flush()` has finished successfully.  The way that you know that that has happened is that the `flush()` call returns.

On the other hand, if you want some assurance that the data has (all) been delivered to the remote machine, or that the remote application has read it (all) ... there is no way to know that based on the Socket or OutputStream APIs.  The normal way to get that sort of assurance is to have the remote application send an "reply" in response, and read it in the local side.

---

> In the following code, the flush() method is run in parallel with the BufferedReader.read() method and the socket output is immediately blocked by the input read resulting in something that resembles a deadlock.

The code that you are talking about is basically the correct approach.  The way to wait for the response is to read it like that.

If it is not working, then you need to compare what the client and server side are doing:

- Is the server waiting for the client to send something more?  Maybe an end of line sequence?
- Did the server sends the response?
- Did it `flush()` the response?

A mismatch between what the client and server are doing *can* lead to a form or deadlock, but the solution is to fix the mismatch.  Waiting for some kind of hypothetical confirmation of the `flush()` is not the answer.

**UPDATE**

The problem is indeed a mismatch.  For example, the server writes `"ack"` but the client expects `"ack\n"`.  The same happens in the client -> server case ... unless `message` always ends with a newline.

Comment: Hi Stephen, my purpose is to check whether the message was received on the server side. My target sequence would be something like:

(1) Client sends message
(2) Server receives message
(3) Server sends ACK
(4) Client receives ACK

The problem is that, as Socket is implemented, listening for input blocks the output thread. And, even though I would expect the output to run synchronously, it doesn't. (1) and (4) get processed in parallel.

What I would like to do is run (4) after the socket is no longer busy processing step (1).

Comment: Show us the server-side code. *"The problem is that, as Socket is implemented, listening for input blocks the output thread."* - That is not true.

Comment: I've added the ServerSocket part.

Comment: As I've tested it, the process doesn't complete step (1). step (2) .. (4) don't run either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem. First, I ran in to some kind of blocking state too, until I realized, I was using `readLine` at Server-side, too. But the message I was sending did not have a concluding `\n`. Therefore, the serversocket was still waiting at its `InputStream` without sending the client the `ACK` through its `OutputStream`. I think, `@Global Variable` is right.